# jQuery TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function on AJAX submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, typeerror, .post

Does anybody see a problem with the following?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#ajax-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#result").html('Sending…').fadeIn();
        var fields = '{';
        $('#ajax-form').filter(':input').each(function() {
            fields = fields + $(this).attr("name")+' : '+$(this).val()+', ';
        });
        fields = fields + '}';
        url = '/scripts/form-submit.php';

        $.post(url,fields, function(data, respText, xhr){
            alert('ok-'+data+'-'+respText+'-'+xhr);
        })
        .error(function(d) {
            alert('no good');
        });
    });
});
```

In Inspector, I get the following error on submit:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (near '....error(function(d) {...')

on the line that closes .error ( `});` ).  That's line 17.

On submit I get one alert which reads: "`ok--success-[object XMLHttpRequest]`". The script I'm submitting to is supposed to send an email and return "It worked" as AJAX response data, and the email is never sent nor is the response received. I know the script works, because when I post do it regularly (not asynchronously), it all works perfectly.

Any insight is very appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: why dont you use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) instead of creating `fields` manually

Comment: Good call, thanks. That actually made the server script work (email sent), but I still receive the TypeError error.  Any idea what causes that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to generate post **data**

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/scripts/form-submit.php",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success:function(response){
                    alert('ok-'+data+'-'+respText+'-'+xhr);
                    alert("Details saved successfully!!!");
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }                  
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in your variable `fields`, which seems to be a json data, but you failed to wrap the value in quotes as a string
here is a reference from jQuery:

`jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] ) ... dataTypeThe type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html)`

it treats your data type as json, but actually it is invalid

Comment: Thanks, I switched it to use the serialize() method, since that was much easier.  You're right, though, fields was invalid.